# Maven - javax.annotation with Java 10

Tags: java, maven, java-10

I have these args at Maven:

```
<compilerArgs>
    <arg>--add-exports</arg>
    <arg>java.base/jdk.internal=tools.jar</arg>
    <arg>--add-modules</arg>
    <arg>java.xml.ws.annotation</arg>
</compilerArgs>
```

I still have a issue that can't find **javax.annotation** package:

> ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct

**UPD:**

Entire output of error: https://pastebin.com/LBFuXTeg

It seems the error occurs with `afterburner.fx` framework:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.airhacks</groupId>
    <artifactId>afterburner.fx</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Version of plugins:

- maven-compiler-plugin - 3.8.0
- maven-shade-plugin - 3.1.1
- maven-jar-plugin - 3.1.0

Entire Maven `pom` file: https://pastebin.com/zkYH0BAg

> Now, I use this dependency: `javax.annotation-api`
>
> With him, all runs successful.

Comment: The details are not sufficient to determine why the class is not resolved, for e.g. are you using module descriptor or an external dependency for the class? if yes, what module name and what dependency(including version). also, how are you building the project, using what plugin versions etc?

Comment: Assuming you want to use `PostConstruct` from the [deprecated Java EE module _java.xml.ws.annotation_](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-migration-guide/#Dependencies-On-Java-EE-Modules), you are doing the right thing, so we need more information to help. Please provide what nullpointer asked for.

Comment: You can make the compiler args a little cleaner with `<arg>--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal=tools.jar</arg>` and `<arg>--add-modules=java.xml.ws.annotation</arg>`.

Comment: ClassNotFoundException is a run-time exception, not a compile-time error. I think we need to see the command used to run the thing that is failing.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post.